# Some easy way to abandon Blogger sites to get more control over things such as DNS?

Tags: blogger

I am fed up Blogger's misleading error reports. The issue looks like this simple [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) (a few text file settings) but Blogger requires me something impossible that some other blogger user preserving my domain should stop using my domain (apparently just one line to fix), totally impossible for me (I do not know the email of the preserver and I am tired to start up some official procedure against the other user). So I want some substitutes. If I export my Blogger XML content -- can I easily use it with independent hosting with my comp?I mean whether there are some service that can read the Blogger XML and I can install it to my server?

Btw I think the "other user" is the old version of the site with different url that is now removed. I think the real problem is messed up DNS handling in Blogger. Any idea how I can privately contact blogger devs about the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There certainly are other blog engines out there that can read blogger xml files. wordpress can.

I would strongly suggest trying to figure out what's going on with the DNS entries, though, since it's possible that other stuff will also have problems with it. In the mean time you could certainly install some other blogging software and see if it just works, i assume a lot of them will be able to import blogger content.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Blogger's [Export Blog](http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=97416) function to create a backup of your blog, then use the "Import from Blogger" function with a blogging application like [WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content) which is hosted elsewhere.